# How to beautify/prettify a Json/JS file in a node.js script

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, prettify

I am searching a way to prettify Json files in a node.js script (not CLI). I found a lot of npm beautifier packages, but none that can simply beautify directly a file.

There is esbeautifier that do what I am searching to do, but the exemples only shows CLI commands: https://github.com/royriojas/esbeautifier Is there a way to use it in a Javascript?

Comment: It's not clear whether you want to beautify JS or JSON files? are we talking about code or json?

Comment: I am searching something that do the same than the Notepad++ plugin JSTool>JSFormat

Comment: in other terms, it corrects indents, spaces and line breaks. My use right now is for Json files, but I think that the process is similar for JS, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the tool [esformatter](https://github.com/millermedeiros/esformatter).

edit by @jck: here is JS snippet that works using fs:

```
var esformatter = require('esformatter');
var fs = require('fs');
var filename = "./myFile.json";
var codeStr = fs.readFileSync(filename).toString();
var formattedCode = esformatter.format(codeStr);
fs.writeFile(filename, formattedCode);
```

Comment: As I see esformatter in JS outputs the data but doesn't modify the file. The only way to use it is to use fs to write the file again, right? Is there no module than can simply beautify and overwrite a file in a single JS method?

Comment: you can write your own function for that, should be simple enough.

Comment: @bilalba it's not so simple because it has to deal with callbacks. I tried `fs.writeFile('myFile.json', esformater.format(fs.readFileSync('myFile.json').toString()));`, and of course it didn't work. I am surprised that no module can do that directly.

Comment: ok TY @bilalba I made it worked, it just needs to separate instructions correctly.

Answer (score 20):

You can prettyprint JSON easily by providing [parameters to `JSON.stringify()`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Many people use this kind of call to prettyprint JSON output. It's still valid JSON, it just contains indentation and newlines.

```
 JSON.stringify(myObject, null, 2);
```

Comment: by far the best answer. so much better in fact that im compelled to downvote the other answers to let this one rise up

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what i want, and no need to call some additional module. I was already using JSON.stringify(). So i just had to add "null" and "2" as additional arguments to the function.

Comment: How is this Not the top and selected answer?! Thanks for pointing this out to beautify a json file!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, check out [prettyjson](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prettyjson)! It has been great for me!